CI on github: incomplete log
This is about CI in https://github.com/Reissner/latex-maven-plugin.
There you can see the complete ./.github/workflows/maven.yml configuring the workflow.
Many things don't work as I expect.
For example this:
[INFO] Processing LaTeX file 'src/site/tex/./docClasses/useBeamerPres.tex'. 
[INFO] Skipping targets [html]. 
[INFO] Checking source. 
++pdf TS meta: 0
++pdf TS file: 1724789480
[INFO] Process with timestamp 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z (0sec)
[INFO] Converting into pdf format. 
Error:  EEX01: Running lualatex failed with return code 1. 
Error:  EEX02: Running lualatex failed: No target file 'useBeamerPres.pdf' written. 
Error:  EAP01: Running lualatex failed. Errors logged in 'useBeamerPres.log'. 
Error:  EEX01: Running lualatex failed with return code 1. 
Error:  EEX02: Running lualatex failed: No target file 'useBeamerPres.pdf' written. 
Error:  EAP01: Running lualatex failed. Errors logged in 'useBeamerPres.log'. 

meaning that lualatex useBeamerPres.tex could not create useBeamerPres.pdf.
Since lualatex also creates a log file, even in case of errors,
I decided to print the log file onto the console.
The according lines in maven.yml are
    - name: write logs
      run: cat src/site/tex/./docClasses/useBeamerPres.log
      working-directory: ./maven-latex-plugin

But the file seems truncated so I cannot figure out the problem.
last lines are
 \pgfmath@stack@operand=\toks24
\pgfmath@stack@operation=\toks25
)
(/opt/hostedtoolcache/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.
code.tex)

and I cannot see indication of an error.
What else could be wrong?

That is expected behaviour. Whenever a step completes with a non-zero exit code, all further steps are skipped. If you want to execute your write logs step, you need to change this default behaviour by telling GitHub to always run it:
- name: write logs
  if: always()
  run: cat src/site/tex/./docClasses/useBeamerPres.log
  working-directory: ./maven-latex-plugin


a I told mvn --fail-never. Else my write logs step would not have been executed at all.
The problem is that its output is truncated.But anyway a good hint.
